# Kivy quiz app in python to add print score after correct answer

Tags: python, kivy

`enter code here`I want to print score after every correct answer of my quiz game in kivy.I don't know how to print incremented score after every correct answer.

Code:

```py
class RootWidget(Widget):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    label_text = StringProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 0
        self.label_text =str(self.count)
    def increment(self,*args):
        self.count +=1
        self.label_text = str(self.count)
        print(self.label_text)

class Score1(Screen):
    label_text = StringProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Score1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 0
        self.label_text =str(self.count)
    def increment(self,*args):
        self.count +=1
        self.label_text = str(self.count)
        print(self.label_text)
```

kv file:

```
<ThirdScreen>:
    name:'3'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"

        Label:
            text:"Who amongst the follwing had called Rabindranath Tagore as THE GREAT SENTINEL?"
            font_size:20
        Button:
            text:'Abdul Kalam Azad'
            size:30,30
            on_release:app.root.current="4"
        Button:
            text:"Mahatma Gandhi"
            size:30,30
            on_press:root.increment()
            on_release:app.root.current="4"
        Button:
            text:'Dr. Rajendra Prasad'
            size:30,30
            on_release:app.root.current="4"
        Button:
            text:'Subhash Chandra Bose'
            size:30,30
            on_release:app.root.current="4"
<Score1>:
    name:'s'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text:root.label_text
        Button:
            text: "Next"

            on_release:app.root.current='3'
            on_release:app.root.current='4'
            on_release:app.root.current='5'
            on_release:app.root.current='6'
            on_release:app.root.current='7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a label on your page. Design your label like **in .kv**:

```
Label:
    text: root.current_score
```

Also you need to set current_score **in .py** file like:

```
current_score = NumericProperty(0)
```

Now on , you just need to check answers and increase-decrease your score in function on .py file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean showing score on the screen, you should use something like label instead of print.